# How to return additional node depending on current node attribute

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domxpath

We have a structure like this:

```
<class>
  <class-intro>
    <indication>Some content</indication>
  </class-intro>

  <article>
    <indication>Special content</indication>
  </article>

  <article includeclass="no">
    <indication>Different content</indication>
  </article>
</class>
```

I'm trying to select these with XQuery/XPath on a per article basis:

```
indication | node()[not(@includeclass) | @includeclass='yes']/ancestor::class/class-intro/indication
```

Note - I'm using PHP's http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

```
// $xpath is a DOMXPath for the above document
$articles = $xpath->query("//article");

$indications = array();
foreach ($articles as $article) {
  $indications[] = $xpath->query(
    "indication | node()[not(@includeclass) | @includeclass='yes']/ancestor::class/class-intro/indication",
    $article
  );
}

var_dump($indications);
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
array(
  0 => array(
    0 => "Some content",
    1 => "Special content",
  ),
  1 => array(
    0 => "Different content",
  ),
);
```

But I am getting:

```
array(
  0 => array(
    0 => "Some content",
    1 => "Special content",
  ),
  1 => array(
    0 => "Some content",
    1 => "Different content",
  ),
);
```

Comment: `$articles = $xpath->query("//article[@includeclass='no']/indication");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because `not(@includeclass)` is always evaluates to `true` for every `node()` in this context, since none of child element of `article` has attribute `includeclass`.

You should've used `self` axis to references current context node i.e use `self::node()` instead of `node()`, because `includeclass` attribute belongs to current context element `article`, not to the child node :

```
self::node()[not(@includeclass) or @includeclass='yes']/ancestor::class/.....
```